# File not found : libgfl190.dll in vb 6.0

Tags: dll, vb6, driver, missing-data, webusercontrol

I am trying to run our User Controller using TwainDriver. it also include the TIF2JPG Converter. When the converter function runs, at first is display the error cannot open the ActiveX Controller so i decided to re run the dll, un-registering and registering again the dll but after that another new error shows.

Run time error '53'

File not found : libgfl190.dll

Comment: Please add some more details, and a question: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi I am using vb 6.0, the OS that i am using with the vb 6.0 is windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

the ActiveX control rely on that dll (libgfl190.dll) but it can not find it. put the dll in %windir%\system32 (32 bit) or %windir%\syswow64\ (64 bit)

Comment: i tried placing the libgfl190.dll ti System32 but still same issue